# how to update the state of app.js using other component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using native-CLI to build a react-native app. Everything is working fine, but when I log in to the user through API, I receive token and other values. I set them in AsyncStorage and it should jump to the buyer dashboard screen but it can't but when I refresh the app then it goes to the buyer dashboard. Basically, it's not refreshing the app.js after pressing the login button it should refresh the app.js also.

**LoginButtonCode**

```
const login = async () => {
        if (name != '' && password != '') {
            const login_Credentials = new FormData();
            login_Credentials.append('username', name);
            login_Credentials.append('password', password);
            setPress(true)
            await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: api + 'login/',
                data: login_Credentials,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            }).then(async function (response) {
                if (response.data.Success == true) {
                    const token = response.data.token.toString();
                    const super_user_status = response.data.super_user_status.toString();
                    const isLoggedIn = "1"
                    console.log('Logged In and set Storgae')
                    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['isLoggedIn',isLoggedIn],['token', token], ['super_user_status', super_user_status]])
                    setName('')
                    setPassword('')
                    setPress(false)
                } else if (response.data.Success == false) {
                    setPress(false)
                    setErrorMsg(response.data.Error)
                    setName('')
                    setPassword('')
                    
                }
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response, "error");
            })
        } else {
            setErrorMsg('Please Enter Username/Password.')
        }
    }
```

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
  const [role, setRole] = useState('seller')

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    getKeysData(dataKeys)
  },[]) 

  const dataKeys = ['token', 'super_user_status', 'isLoggedIn'];    
  const getKeysData = async (keys) => {
    const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
    const aData = stores.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
    const token = aData[0]['token']
    const super_user_status = aData[1]['super_user_status']
    const isLoggedIn = aData[2]['isLoggedIn']
    console.log('token',token)
    console.log('SuperUser', super_user_status)
    console.log('Log',isLoggedIn)
    if(isLoggedIn == '1'){
      setUser(true)
    }else{
      setUser(false)
    }
    }
  //AsyncStorage.clear()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      { user == false ?
        <AuthStackScreen />
        :
        <BuyerDashboardStackScreens />
      }

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

I use AsyncStorage to update the state in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the `AsyncStorage` is async, the user is false at the beginning and the state is not loaded to the state. You should set a loading state and until the state is not loaded from the `AsyncStorage` you show a splash screen. When you login, set the user state from the response.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
const [role, setRole] = useState('seller')
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
...
const getKeysData =() => {
  // wait for storage data
  // setUser
  setIsLoading(false)
}
...
if(isLoading) return <Loader />
return <Navigation.../>
```

Comment: according to you, I understand that I need to use splashscreen to set the loading state

Comment: I mean in the login function after the success response, you haven't set the user state. Thats misssing.

Comment: but user state is in app.js and login function is in the separate login component file.

Comment: Well, you prolly need a UserContext to store user state and pass to app and login component. Do you know context?

Comment: i dont know about context.